# How to display metric comparison between certain date and previous time period?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a data source consisting of date, URL, and metric (number) which changes for each URL from date to date.

So I built a report with this setup:

- date as Date Range Dimension,
- URL as Dimension,
- metric (average) as Metric,
- default date range as today,
- comparison between date and previous time period.

With this setup, I got the metric for today for each URL and the comparison between today and yesterday. This works like a charm.

Then I wanted to see the average metric for today in comparison to yesterday and changed the setup to this:

- date as Date Range Dimension,
- date as Dimension,
- metric (average) as Metric (to see the average metric for today and comparison of it with yesterday)

Now I see the average metric's value for today, as it should - **but no comparison value**.

What am I doing wrong? How do I display the comparison of metric between then date and the previous time period?

**EDIT 1**: Here is [report link with editing rights](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/b261cecf-b51a-4ed2-8908-004558de70b5). And here is the [data source](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PtskmTMbHfSK192uLsvrzPzk0qERGK08SL3obYMtj8Q/edit?usp=sharing) - Google Sheets document.

On the screenshot you see:

- in the top table every URL with its today's metric and comparison to yesterday,
- in the bottom table you see the date with the average metric for today - but no comparison value.

**Edit 2**: I added to the data source (Google Sheets) an additional column where the date is 100% correctly recognized by Google Sheets as date (not as DateTime, as in original column). But no success here too.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a working demo that reproduces your problem? Although you have described your problem well, it'll help a lot to have a working demo.

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz sure, added the link to report with editor rights.

Comment: I can't think in anything, but a bug. Notice that if you select "Show summary row" the delta value appear in the Grand total row. However, I am inclined to think this bug may be related with your DateTime field (this kind of field often trigger bugs in my reports). Can you try to make your DateTime field a Date field directly in the Data Source? (create a new column in the data source, instead of changing granularity in the visual or creating a calculated column in Data Studio)

Comment: Yes, i did so as you said - added to the data source (Google Sheets) additional column where the date is 100% correctly recognized by Google Sheets as date. But no success here too. Here  is the link to the data source: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PtskmTMbHfSK192uLsvrzPzk0qERGK08SL3obYMtj8Q/edit?usp=sharing